# How can I provide a useState to a context in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

```
export const Comp = () => {
  const {val, change} = useContext(ProviderContext)

  return (
    <TextField>
      onChange={({target}) => {
      change(target)
    }}
      value={val}
    </TextField>
  );
}


describe('test', ()=>{
  let container = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  //This doesn't work since it's not a react component

  const [val, setVal] = useState();

  const change = (e)=>{
    setVal(e.value)
  }

  it('test', ()=>{
    act(() => {
      render(
        <ProviderContext.Provider value={{
          val,
          change,
        }}>
          <Comp />
        </ProviderContext.Provider>
      ), container
    });
  })

})
```

When the users inputs text in the field, it calls the TextField's onChange, which calls the "change" function from the context, which updates the 'val' state from the context.

thank you

Comment: It's unclear why you need useState for that. What exacty is the problem with providing raw `val` value?

Comment: Because the Comp component needs a hook. It rerenders when setVal is called

Comment: This seems to be XY problem. The component doesn't require a hook because it only needs a value. If you need to rerender component tree this can be done several ways. You didn't post your testing setup so I assume you use React test utils that are low level. In this case this is done by wrapping a component with dummy component, if it's functional it will use useState to trigger a re-render and thus you avoid a problem specified in the question. If you use higher level libs like RTL that the answer suggests, they provide their own ways to (re)render, no need for `act`, `useState`, etc.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I've updated the code. It needs a hook since "val" is the value of the MaterialUI TextField. The onChange function of the textfield calls the change function from the context, which updates the state.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you needed state setter only to rerender the component from the outside. Here you could just provide Jest spy as `change` and assert that it was called. Since a way how a context is updated on new state is warranted by React, I don't see value in testing it with useState specifically. You can surely go this way but it's more comfortable to do blackbox testing with RTL than with plain React renderer since the former is a superset of the latter.

Comment: How can I trigger the rerender?

Comment: RTL has `rerender`, Enzyme has `setProps`. If you don't use them, you need to reinvent the wheel with dummy component wrapper and use `forceUpdate` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use renderHook from react testing library

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'

it('test', ()=>{

  const [val, setVal] = renderHook(() => useState());

  act(() => {
    render(
      <ProviderContext.Provider value={{
        val,
      }}>
        <Comp />
        </ProviderContext.Provider>
    ), container
  });
})
```

Comment: renderHook is usually needed to test custom hooks. Since RTL was suggested, it provides rerendering and doesn't need useState trick at all.

Comment: @EstusFlask what about if we are passing in a setter from useState, how do we do that?